# Can't include facebook inside my codeigniter project

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I wanted to include the facebook login inside my application. This is the sample code which I was provided with:

```
    <?php

require 'facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'my api goes here',
  'secret' => 'my api secret goes here',
  'cookie' => true,
));

// We may or may not have this data based on a $_GET or $_COOKIE based session.
//
// If we get a session here, it means we found a correctly signed session using
// the Application Secret only Facebook and the Application know. We dont know
// if it is still valid until we make an API call using the session. A session
// can become invalid if it has already expired (should not be getting the
// session back in this case) or if the user logged out of Facebook.
$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--
      We use the JS SDK to provide a richer user experience. For more info,
      look here: http://github.com/facebook/connect-js
    -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>',
          session : <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });

        // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>


    <h1><a href="example.php">php-sdk</a></h1>

    <?php if ($me): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">
      <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif">
    </a>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div>
      Using JavaScript &amp; XFBML: <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    </div>
    <div>
      Without using JavaScript &amp; XFBML:
      <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">
        <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">
      </a>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Session</h3>
    <?php if ($me): ?>
    <pre><?php print_r($session); ?></pre>

    <h3>You</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $uid; ?>/picture">
    <?php echo $me['name']; ?>
    <?php echo $me['education'][0]['school']['name']; ?>

    <h3>Your User Object</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($me); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
    <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now - this works well but when I'm trying to include that in my code igniter view file it's not allowing me to login due to an error. In the code where it says 'my api goes here' and 'my api secret goes here' I'm obviously inserting my app data. Does any of you encountered similar issue? When I click login I'm getting this error: An error occurred with MY APP. Please try again later.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried any of these two CodeIgniter libraries for Facebook?

- http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/
- http://brandonbeasley.com/blog/facebook-api-codeigniter/

UPDATE: Sadly these links are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

My partner just made a library and indepth tut to help with this:
http://hitsend.ca/2010/10/facebook-connect-user-authentication-using-the-new-graph-api-in-codeigniter/

Let us know what you think. We needed it for our uses, and figured it was a common problem.
It uses the new graph api, not the old one. That solves A LOT of problems.

Let us know what you think.